# Populating unbound column with fix value reference to other table

Tags: acumatica

I have extended a APTran DAC for Bills and Adjustments screen (ID - AP301000).
I am trying to populate a value from different table based on the current line item.

The value I need is from CrossReference based on current Inventory on line item and VendorID of current Bill.

Below is the code. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

```html
public class string_VendorType : Constant<string>
{
 public string_VendorType() : base("0VPN")
 { }
}

protected string _UsrVendorPartNum;

[PXString(50)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Part Number", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search2<INItemXRef.alternateID,
 LeftJoin<InventoryItem, On<INItemXRef.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>,
  LeftJoin<APTran, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<APTran.inventoryID>>,
   LeftJoin<APInvoice, On<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<APTran.refNbr>,
    And<APInvoice.vendorID, Equal<INItemXRef.bAccountID>>>>>>,
 Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<APTran.inventoryID>>,
  And<INItemXRef.alternateType, Equal<string_VendorType>,
   And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Current<APTran.refNbr>>>>>>))]

public virtual string UsrVendorPartNum
{
 get
 {
  return _UsrVendorPartNum;
 }
 set
 {
  _UsrVendorPartNum = value;
 }
}
public abstract class usrVendorPartNum : IBqlField { }
```

However, the value isn't populating. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following working (using PXUnboundDefault). The query you have can be simplified to the following working example:

```
public class APTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTran>
{
    protected string _UsrVendorPartNum;

    [PXString(50)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Part Number", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
    [PXUnboundDefault(typeof(Search<INItemXRef.alternateID,
        Where<INItemXRef.inventoryID, Equal<Current<APTran.inventoryID>>,
            And<INItemXRef.alternateType, Equal<INAlternateType.vPN>,
                And<INItemXRef.bAccountID, Equal<Current<APTran.vendorID>>>>>>))]
    public virtual string UsrVendorPartNum
    {
        get
        {
            return _UsrVendorPartNum;
        }
        set
        {
            _UsrVendorPartNum = value;
        }
    }
    public abstract class usrVendorPartNum : IBqlField { }
}
```

Note that you do not need to create your own constant. You can reuse `INAlternateType` and the `vPN` constant.

*Simply for reference...*

I would say if this was a DB field you could look into using the `AlternativeItemAttribute`, however it requires a `subitem` field which oddly `APTran` does not have in it.

Example usage of `AlternativeItemAttribute` on `POLine.AlternateID`:

```
public abstract class alternateID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected String _AlternateID;      
[AlternativeItem(INPrimaryAlternateType.VPN, typeof(POLine.vendorID), typeof(POLine.inventoryID), typeof(POLine.subItemID))]
public virtual String AlternateID
{
    get
    {
        return this._AlternateID;
    }
    set
    {
        this._AlternateID = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't helped.

Comment: can you confirm the Current<> values have a current value at the time the default is executing?

Comment: How do I confirm that in DAC? I debugged and tried to look for APTran.refNbr and it has value. Let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: added something else to try... could be a late set of the field based on your formula (the formula is firing before the fields it needs has a value)

Comment: That didn't helped too

Comment: I have added PXFormula attribute to the field. But still it is not populating VendorPartNumber from the CrossReference.

Comment: Thank you Brendan. The working code you provide. I have also include PXFormula attribute also so that VendorPartNumber is populated once user changes the inventoryid in line item. [PXFormula(typeof(Default<APTran.refNbr, APTran.inventoryID>))]

Comment: perfect. I did not test changes so that sound neccessary. Also because its a unbounddefault it should auto refresh when the user refreshes the grid/page without the formula.